# How can I generate a series of repeating numbers in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, generate-series

In PostgreSQL, is it possible to generate a series of repeating numbers? For example, I want to generate the numbers 1 to 10, with each number repeated 3 times:

```
1
1
1
2
2
2
3
3
3
.. and so on.
```

Comment: generate_series(3, 32) / 3 ??

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You could cross join it to a series of 3:

```
SELECT a.n
from generate_series(1, 100) as a(n), generate_series(1, 3)
```

Comment: Does this need ordering, or is the join guaranteed to be in the right order already?

Comment: @radio it will be in order. It’s not “guaranteed”, but as a matter of practicality it will always be ordered.

Answer (score 21):

You could try integer division like this:

```
SELECT generate_series(3, 100) / 3
```

Comment: great! more handy compared to the selected answer.

Comment: So elegant! In general terms should be `generate_series(n,n*N) / n` where `n` = repeatition and `N` = max number

Answer (score 8):

For such small numbers `CROSS JOIN` two [`VALUES`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-values.html) expressions:

```
SELECT n
FROM  (VALUES (1),(2),(3)) x(r)  -- repetitions (values are not used)
     ,(VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) y(n); -- numbers
```

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/3010)

This works for *any* sequence of numbers (including repeated or irregular patterns).
For anything bigger and with regular sequential pattern use [`generate_series()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html) as has been suggested.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if you can do use generate_series like that in PostgreSQL, but i would try a cross join:

```
SELECT x FROM
  (SELECT generate_series(1, 10) AS x) t1, 
  (SELECT generate_series(1, 3) as y) t2
```

**Edit:**

As generate_series already returns a table there's no need for SELECT in a Derived Table:

```
SELECT x FROM
  generate_series(1, 10) AS x, 
  generate_series(1, 3) as y
```

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT generate_series(1, 10)) A
JOIN (
  SELECT generate_series(1, 3)
) B ON (TRUE)
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d41d8

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT a.x from generate_series(0, 100) as a(x), generate_series(1, 3)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just another options:

```
select generate_series(1, 3) from generate_series(1, 10)

select generate_series(1, 30) % 10 + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was looking for a table with a column with data like following to inner join with other tables with a similar column.

```sql
with
  hours(hour) AS (
    select concat(extract(hour from n), ' of ', n::date) as hour
    from
    generate_series(timestamp '2004-03-07', '2004-08-16', '1 hour')
    as a(n)
  )
  
  select * from hours
```

### Result

Link to the fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7VagpVQwio9e6DVjSwMsTL/1
[image]

### Actual Implementation

[image]

---

I hope this is helpful.