# PostgresQL for each row, generate new rows and merge

Tags: postgresql

I have a table called **example** that looks as follows:

```
ID | MIN | MAX |
1  | 1   |  5  |
2  | 34  | 38  |
```

I need to take each ID and loop from it's min to max, incrementing by 2 and thus get the following **WITHOUT** using `INSERT` statements, thus in a `SELECT`:

```
ID | INDEX | VALUE
1  |  1    |   1
1  |  2    |   3
1  |  3    |   5
2  |  1    |   34
2  |  2    |   36
2  |  3    |   38
```

Any ideas of how to do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23358333/1048572

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [set-returning function `generate_series`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html) does exactly that:

```
SELECT
  id,
  generate_series(1, (max-min)/2+1) AS index,
  generate_series(min, max, 2) AS value
FROM
  example;
```

<sup>([online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=61af8ed2aba3675df55704bf20ff46d8))</sup>

The index can alternatively be generated with `RANK()` ([example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=48fe8541513566c8eb6cf1756420cdd0), see also @a_horse_­with_­no_­name's answer) if you don't want to rely on the parallel sets.

Comment: The online demo was a nice touch!

Answer (score 2):

Use `generate_series()` to generate the numbers and a window function to calculate the index:

```
select e.id, 
       row_number() over (partition by e.id order by g.value) as index,
       g.value
from example e
  cross join generate_series(e.min, e.max, 2) as g(value);
```